What is the square of a matrix quadratic form in block matrix form?
I am seeking to square a quadratic function in matrix form in an attempt to make the resulting matrix of coefficients positive-semi definite for mean squared error analysis.
I have the following quadratic function in matrix form:
$$
 \mathbf{x}^TA\mathbf{x} = 
\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\\\hline1\end{bmatrix}^T
{\LARGE A}
\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\\\hline1\end{bmatrix} = 0
$$
...where A is a symmetric matrix, but not positive semi-definite.
I seek to square the function to arrive at the block matrix form:
$$ (\mathbf{x}^TA\mathbf{x})^2 =
\mathbf{y}^TB\mathbf{y} = 
\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\\\hline1\\\hline x^2\\y^2\\z^2\end{bmatrix}^T
{\LARGE B}
\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\\\hline1\\\hline x^2\\y^2\\z^2\end{bmatrix}
= 0$$
... where B is a square block matrix, which is both symmetric and positive semi-definite.
Q: What is the method to construct B from A using matrix operations?
I am able to construct B by expanding out $(\mathbf{x}^TA\mathbf{x})^2$, and building B from scratch, but there must be an easier way to do this...?
As an aside, I would be content with the form below for y if it is easier to arrive at (and may be more general):
$$\mathbf{y}^TB\mathbf{y} = \begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\\1\\\hline x^2\\y^2\\z^2\\1^2\end{bmatrix}^T
{\LARGE B}
\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\\1\\\hline x^2\\y^2\\z^2\\1^2\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{x}\\\hline diag(\mathbf{x}\bullet\mathbf{x}^T)\end{bmatrix}^T
{\Large B}
\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{x}\\\hline diag(\mathbf{x}\bullet\mathbf{x}^T)\end{bmatrix}
$$

It doesn't necessarily exist.
Consider the quadratic form  $f(x,y,z,t)=xy+zt$, we have that $f(x,y,z,t)^2=x^2y^2+z^2t^2+2xyzt$. Even evaluating $t=1$ we see that the term $2xyzt$ cannot be obtain from a bilinear form in the variable $x,y,z,t,x^2,y^2,z^2,t^2$, as the only terms of degree 4 that you can obtain are of the form $u^2v^2$. Therefore there cannot be a matrix $B$ (independent of the variable) satisfying what you want in all generalities.

Thank you, that is a good spot.  For B to exist, I can only think that A must be a diagonal, or some sparse, non-full rank matrix. The rows/columns along the "1" variable can also be occupied.  Very little else.
